# Searching and matching keyword of google sheet (inconsistent data property) data-set using GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm learning how to move selected row data to another google sheet and I resolved a issue with rowIndex in my [Related previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77028919/google-appscript-rowindex-variable-is-not-passed-to-function). This question is related same example but regarding **searchData(keyword)**.

here is code.

```
function searchData(keyword) {
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SOURCE_ID').getSheetByName('Data');
  var data = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var matchingRows = [];

  // Create a regular expression to match 12-digit numbers and 9-digit numbers with letters
  var regex = new RegExp(keyword, 'i'); // 'i' flag for case-insensitive search

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var cellValue = data[i][0].toString();

    // Use the regular expression to test for a match
    if (regex.test(cellValue)) {
      matchingRows.push({ data: data[i], rowIndex: i });
    }
  }

  return matchingRows;
}
```

My source sheet has more than 300 columns. some columns are empty and some columns are dates, strings... my target is to search first column data (RegExp), find rowIndex, display that row and move. But, I inspect html and error is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')`

[image]

I noticed when there is date filled cell data, row data not displaying.
As I'm beginner of coding, I didn't expect `searchData(keyword)` will affect with cell data in the row. Please guide me.

Here I added the sample sheets. Source sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qJUYMu0ElRQvWdxdXn5vOdKKxwUBPHWztQ4gcS3qVy4/edit?usp=sharing) and Target sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YYYf9a1XfYwxCzKIdV_qVLJcmD1N1IRAtDGdp-rOIGk/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your showing image and your script, I guessed that the reason for your current issue might be due to that the date object is included in the row value. [Ref(Author: me)](https://medium.com/google-cloud/report-values-to-transfer-between-javascript-and-google-apps-script-with-google-script-run-b1420ba16f79)
If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function searchData(keyword) {
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SOURCE_ID').getSheetByName('Data');
  var data = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues(); // <--- Modified
  var matchingRows = [];

  // Create a regular expression to match 12-digit numbers and 9-digit numbers with letters
  var regex = new RegExp(keyword, 'i'); // 'i' flag for case-insensitive search

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var cellValue = data[i][0].toString();

    // Use the regular expression to test for a match
    if (regex.test(cellValue)) {
      matchingRows.push({ data: data[i], rowIndex: i });
    }
  }

  return matchingRows;
}
```

- When this modified script is used, the cell display values are retrieved without including the date object.

#### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### References:

- [Report: Values to transfer between Javascript and Google Apps Script with “google.script.run” (Author: me)](https://medium.com/google-cloud/report-values-to-transfer-between-javascript-and-google-apps-script-with-google-script-run-b1420ba16f79)
- [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
function searchData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var matchingRows = sh.getDataRange().getValues().filter(r => r[0] == 14 );//searching for row with column one equal to 14
  osh.clearContents();
  osh.getRange(1,1,matchingRows.length,matchingRows[0].length).setValues(matchingRows);
}
```

My Data:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 | COL11 | COL12 | COL13 | COL14 | COL15 | COL16 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 8 | 17 | 17 | 1 | 17 | 2 | 20 | 17 | 2 | 14 | 7 | 18 | 18 | 9 | 0 |
| 4 | 16 | 9 | 20 | 1 | 3 | 16 | 0 | 11 | 15 | 16 | 16 | 7 | 4 | 18 | 0 |
| 18 | 6 | 15 | 6 | 2 | 12 | 12 | 15 | 2 | 8 | 19 | 3 | 11 | 1 | 19 | 6 |
| 8 | 20 | 5 | 10 | 5 | 9 | 2 | 7 | 5 | 9 | 16 | 19 | 7 | 18 | 15 | 19 |
| 19 | 6 | 17 | 8 | 18 | 12 | 14 | 3 | 13 | 8 | 12 | 9 | 9 | 17 | 6 | 6 |
| 10 | 20 | 0 | 19 | 17 | 6 | 16 | 14 | 18 | 16 | 7 | 6 | 20 | 0 | 13 | 16 |
| 3 | 9 | 3 | 20 | 13 | 10 | 12 | 19 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 6 | 14 | 16 | 6 | 16 |
| 9 | 8 | 6 | 7 | 16 | 1 | 11 | 12 | 11 | 1 | 19 | 18 | 9 | 15 | 4 | 7 |
| 14 | 11 | 16 | 20 | 9 | 9 | 9 | 8 | 15 | 20 | 5 | 3 | 2 | 11 | 17 | 20 |
| 15 | 3 | 19 | 0 | 5 | 16 | 16 | 12 | 20 | 5 | 5 | 9 | 6 | 16 | 12 | 19 |
| 5 | 14 | 6 | 0 | 11 | 5 | 11 | 15 | 1 | 3 | 17 | 20 | 5 | 16 | 6 | 13 |
| 0 | 7 | 7 | 1 | 5 | 20 | 8 | 3 | 3 | 16 | 8 | 11 | 11 | 8 | 18 | 10 |
| 18 | 16 | 15 | 15 | 4 | 1 | 16 | 3 | 6 | 10 | 20 | 17 | 11 | 1 | 1 | 18 |
| 7 | 7 | 14 | 7 | 11 | 9 | 14 | 11 | 18 | 17 | 10 | 7 | 15 | 8 | 6 | 19 |
| 1 | 6 | 7 | 17 | 15 | 4 | 11 | 8 | 14 | 10 | 6 | 16 | 5 | 16 | 9 | 5 |
| 13 | 5 | 14 | 11 | 3 | 13 | 6 | 8 | 11 | 2 | 16 | 17 | 17 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 14 | 20 | 7 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 6 | 6 | 14 | 17 | 12 | 1 | 20 | 16 | 19 | 4 |
| 1 | 13 | 13 | 1 | 17 | 6 | 19 | 7 | 1 | 7 | 9 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 12 | 9 |
| 2 | 20 | 12 | 3 | 16 | 11 | 5 | 18 | 18 | 12 | 7 | 9 | 8 | 19 | 1 | 6 |
| 14 | 17 | 9 | 8 | 12 | 7 | 11 | 10 | 16 | 19 | 3 | 8 | 8 | 20 | 18 | 8 |
| 20 | 3 | 1 | 15 | 1 | 15 | 1 | 11 | 11 | 19 | 0 | 17 | 20 | 4 | 20 | 1 |

Matching rows:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O | P |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 14 | 11 | 16 | 20 | 9 | 9 | 9 | 8 | 15 | 20 | 5 | 3 | 2 | 11 | 17 | 20 |
| 2 | 14 | 20 | 7 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 6 | 6 | 14 | 17 | 12 | 1 | 20 | 16 | 19 | 4 |
| 3 | 14 | 17 | 9 | 8 | 12 | 7 | 11 | 10 | 16 | 19 | 3 | 8 | 8 | 20 | 18 | 8 |